# Head disappears under Shrinkwrap

Tags: retopology

I'm adding a *Shrinkwrap* to my sculpted head but it kind of disappears under the *Shrinkwrap*; when I hide the *Shrinkwrap* the head is there.

[image]

As you can see the eyes and mouth look to have disappeared

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.